# Extract just the link from "a href"

Tags: xpath

`xmllint sample.xml --xpath "//a[text()='some value']/@href"`

outputs:

`href="http://some.address"`

How can I output just the link without attribute name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmllint sample.xml --xpath "string(//a[text()='some value']/@href)"`

Comment: If there are several attributes it will print only first one...

Comment: is there a way to get all of them?